# JavaMail: reply to all is including the original recipient

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm almost assuming this is a bug in JavaMail API.

I'm doing a `myMessage.reply(true)` to generate a new message. However, despite of the traditional "Reply To All" understanding, JavaMail is including myself (recipient of the first message, `myMessage`) as one of the recipients of the new message (created by the `reply(true)`).
In any email application, doing a Reply to All doesn't add yourself to the new message.

It looks like a bug, no?
Does anyone else have/had this same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is not clear enough.
Do a for loop on `getRecipients` using the `Recipient.TO` as a parameter and then remove yourself from the reply `Message` instance.

Answer (score 3):

JavaMail needs to know what **your** address is.  It determines this using the InternetAddress.getLocalAddress method.  See the [javadocs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#getLocalAddress%28javax.mail.Session%29) for how this works.  It then makes sure that your address doesn't appear in the recipient list of the new message.  If it's not working for you, it's most likely because JavaMail doesn't know what your email address is.

In addition, in the JavaMail reference implementation, the Session property "mail.alternates" can be a list of other email addresses you're known by.  Those will also be eliminated in the recipient list.

Answer (score 1):

The javadocs says it clearly:

> If replyToAll is set, the new Message will be addressed to all recipients of this message. Otherwise, the reply will be addressed to only the sender of this message (using the value of the getReplyTo method).

In a email client you usually (older OWA is not smart enough for example) have the smart behavior because the developers of such app tought about it and decided to make it so, but it is certainly not a bug in javamail.

Comment: **will be addressed to all recipients of this message**. So why the original sender is automatically added? By definition of the word **recipient** the sender is not a recipient.

Comment: @igorjrr: Your tone seems a bit combative. If your goal is to get answers to questions, you've come to the right place. If your goal is to start an argument about Java, then you haven't. Do you really want reply-all to exclude the original sender?

Comment: @igorjrr The sender was a recipient of the message being replied to. Otherwise he wouldn't have received it to reply to.

Comment: @ruakh Yes, and now I'm removing the original recipient from the reply `Message`. And yes, I was arguing about the definition of the method because I don't think it's clear enough.

Comment: @EJP I don't think you can say the sender was a recipient of the original message - otherwise he would receive it in his Inbox, and it's not the case. Unless the sender included himself in the list of TO, CC, or BCC, he is not one of the recipients of the original Message. In fact, if you use the method `getAllRecipients`, you don't see the sender in the results. That said, following strictly what is written in the documentation, the sender wouldn't be included as a recipient of the reply Message (and yes, it's odd to say that - but it's what the documentation says).